# How can I package a scrapy project using cxfreeze?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, py2exe, scrapy

I have a scrapy project that I would like to package all together for a customer using windows without having to manually install dependencies for them. I came across cxfreeze, but I'm not quite sure how it would work with a scrapy project.

I'm thinking I would make some sort of interface and run the scrapy crawler with 'from scrapy.cmdline import execute', but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out py2exe. It works well, you can bundle all the code in one exe.

I suggest you to exclude unused packages to reduce exe size (see py2exe examples on its site)

**UDATE**
 As suggested try also

> [GUI2Exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) is a Graphical User
>   Interface frontend to all the
>   "executable builders" available for
>   the Python programming language. It
>   can be used to build standalone
>   Windows executables, Linux
>   applications and Mac OS application
>   bundles and plugins starting from
>   Python scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I have added GUI2Exe Refs